# Exporting an animated FBX to XNA? (in 3DS Max)

Tags: xna, animation, fbx

I'm now working on an XNA 3D game, and I want to add animated models in it. I came across [this](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/skinned_model) example.  I see there is one FBX file and a few texture files in the content project, and that in the code you can choose which "take" to play. In this code it is "Take_001". Please tell me: When I create and animate my own 3D model in 3DS Max (2012, since I was told it's only possible in this version), how can I define those takes? plus, are any configurations need to be made when exporting FBX from 3DS Max to XNA?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually got it working. Although, I ended up using Blender. I created a bone system for the model, textured it, animated it and when exporting there's an "XNA Strict Options" check mark. I checked it, unchecked it, and then checked "Export Default Take". and it works :)

Answer (score 3):

if you still want to use 3DS Max for your animation takes you can use this:

http://www.turbosquid.com/FullPreview/Index.cfm/ID/701878

Answer (score 1):

Animation in XNA is the one and only reason I did not pursue a game solution in XNA, the Microsoft example is nice, but it is the only animation I ever get to work.

If I remember correctly, you need to write your own BlendingAnimation.

Maybe take a look at CodePlex's XNAnimation, wich is currently being ported to 4.0

http://xnanimation.codeplex.com/

T.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I actually got it working a few days ago! Although, I ended up using Blender. I created a bone system for the model, textured it, animated it and when exporting there's an "XNA Strict Options" check mark. I checked it, unchecked it, and then checked "Export Default Take". and it works :)